# Find indices of mutually exclusive elements between two arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, mutual-exclusion

I have two arrays, and I have found how to identify the mutually exclusive elements with  `np.setxor1d(a,b)`. For example:

```
a = np.random.randint(11, size=10) #first array
b = np.random.randint(11, size=10) #second array
ex = np.setxor1d(a,b)              #mutually exclusive array

a
Out[1]: [1, 5, 3, 7, 6, 0, 10, 10, 0, 9]
b
Out[2]: [1, 9, 8, 6, 3, 5, 8, 0, 3, 10]
ex
Out[3]: [7, 8]
```

Now, I am trying to figure out how to get the indices of the elements of the exclusive array, `ex` for both `a` and `b`. In a way such as `a_mutex_ind` and `b_mutex_ind`. Does anyone know of a clever way to do this WITHOUT a for loop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = np.setxor1d(a, b)
>>> i, = np.nonzero(np.in1d(a, x))
>>> i
array([3])
>>> a[i]
array([7])
```

and similarly for `b`:

```
>>> j, = np.nonzero(np.in1d(b, x))
>>> j
array([2, 6])
>>> b[j]
array([8, 8])
```

Comment: Perfect! One of those "Why didn't I think of that?" things